# Bash script running perfectly fine on Centos 7 and giving exception on Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, cron

> Please find below script

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  dbs=('test_db_1' 'test_db_2') 
  path='/var/backups/'
else
  dbs=( "$@" )
  path='/app/mybackups/'
fi
dbuser='test_user_name'
dbpassword='test_pass_word'
now="$(date +'%d-%m-%Y_%T')"
currentDate="$(date)"
dayToSubtract=365
cd ${path}
echo "location: $path"
for element in ${dbs[@]}
        do
                echo $element
                echo "Starting backup now for db: $element on $now"
                mongodump -u ${dbuser} -p ${dbpassword} --authenticationDatabase 'admin' -d $element --gzip --archive=${element}_$now.archive
                dateToBeRemoved=$(date --date="${currentDate} -${dayToSubtract} day" +%d-%m-%Y)
                echo $dateToBeRemoved
                fileToBeRemoved="${element}_${dateToBeRemoved}"
                echo Removing $fileToBeRemoved
                rm $fileToBeRemoved*
        done
echo All Done!
echo "location: $path"
```

I have been using this script for more than a year for backing up my dbs on the server on a daily basis and I also use it to take manual backups by passing command-line arguments to this script.

Recently I got a new server having ubuntu and its giving following error there

```
daily.sh: 2: daily.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Please find below screenshot for reference:

[image]

After adding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

[image]

Getting same error:

[image]

Ran which bash, got the following

[image]

Added the shebang according to which bash result but still facing same issue
[image]

When running from the current folder:

[image]

check for the BOM:

[image]

**Ubuntu Info:**
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: You're using `sh` to run a `bash` script (that should be in the text, not in the picture), which points to `dash` in Ubuntu, not `bash`.

Comment: Also, please don't attach [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), but copy-and-paste it to the question body with appropriate formatting; in your case it is short enough that no highlighting should be necessary (and even then, there are other possibilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving the old answer below, as it adds context and details. But I think your misunderstanding stems from what you assume `sh yourscript` ought to do.

What it does is to use `sh` (which differs by system, as you noticed ...) as **the interpreter** for the script name you pass.

What you *seem* to intend, though, was

```
sh -c "your command ... whatever it is"
```

Now, why you insist on using `sh` as **the interpreter** when you've full well been told in comments and two answers that this is wrong, I don't know.

If your script is executable, has a proper hashbang and is either located in the `PATH` or invoked with its relative or absolute path, it *will work*.

But by insisting on using `sh` as the interpreter you are basically *actively* sabotaging all attempts to help you, because `sh` is not the same as `sh -c COMMAND`. And if your interpreter isn't Bash, using Bashisms will likely fail (as you witnessed).

And if you want this failure to be "more reliable" you can carve it in stone by using `#!/bin/sh` as the hashbang (instead of the suggested one), which will yield the same outcome as handing your script to `sh` on the command line.

---

You have several issues here. Your screenshot shows your script isn't executable (owned by `root:root` with file mode 0644). So when you are attempting to execute it with `sh` it will use whichever Shell `sh` happens to be on your system.

The reason this fails is threefold:

- your script is not executable and not in the `PATH`
- `sh yourscript` makes it - since it's not executable - use `sh` as the interpreter (which in case of Ubuntu is `dash` and doesn't understand all Bashisms)
- your script is missing a hashbang, which provides the clue for the loader which interpreter to use for your "binary"

If, however, you'd add a hashbang such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

... if you made sure your script contains no [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and if you made sure that it's executable:

```
chmod +x daily_ori.sh
```

... and used a relative path (or added your current path to `PATH`, which - however - is a bad idea!):

```
sh ./daily_ori.sh
```

... this *should* succeed. Unless there is more information that is lacking from your question.

But that last step really calls into question why you insist on executing the script with `sh` in the first place if your intention is to invoke Bash. Simply use a hashbang (whether hardcoded or with `env`) to locate `bash` as interpreter, make sure the script is executable and call it as you normally would ...

---

To check for the BOM use:

```
xxd -g 1 daily_ori.sh|head -n 2
```

... and edit that into your question.

Comment: Updated question please check

Comment: No BOM, so the problem is solved then.

Comment: Can you explain? how? I am still unable to run this bash script?

Comment: @AbdulMoiz yes, I updated my answer accordingly. You keep running your script with `sh` as interpreter, I am not sure why you expect any different outcome? You need to execute it as a command, unless you know you can rely on `sh` being a particular shell/interpreter. And if you can't you must stick to the common denominator, which is POSIX shell dialect.

Comment: @AbdulMoiz : So the script works now ?

Comment: Yes, it works not. I successfully ran it from my current directory by running it as a command as @0xC0000022L mentioned, thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the shebang in the first line of your script :
(From the comment)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

OR If you know the path.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

wherever it is located.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` uses the `PATH` to locate `bash` (or rather whatever _interpreter_ you hand it). So if it's not installed you'll get the same you'd always get in such a case: `/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory` ... because `env` helps to "delegate" to the interpreter it finds. If none is found, you get a meaningful error. Just as if you had given an absolute path to a non-existing `bash` binary: `-bash: ./fle.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L : Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: How would i find the location of this? /usr/bin/bash this does not exists for me and I tried adding both you suggested but both does not work

Comment: @AbdulMoiz : Did you try this -> "#!/usr/bin/env bash" ..

Comment: When I check bash -n it does not give me any error.

Comment: Check the location by using command -> "which bash"  -> This will tell the path of the bash and you can paste it the script as mentioned...

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar: Yes i tried its giving same error sh daily.sh leads
daily.sh: 3: daily.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar: root@leadsearch:/app/cronscripts# which bash result in
"/bin/bash" after this I added "#!/bin/bash" in my first line but still facing same issue.

Comment: so , it shows /bin/bash as output right...so you have to add "#!/bin/bash" as the first line in the script.

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar: still giving the same error, check question I added some screen shots

Comment: @AbdulMoiz : Am wondering , it works for me even without mentioning bash in first line...let me check and come back if i found any..

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar: Its working for me as well on centos 7, but not on ubuntu

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar if you test this on a Ubuntu with `sh` and a file name (without relative or absolute path!) it will also fail _with_ hashbang. The reason is that the hashbang will get ignored and instead `sh` will be used as interpreter of the script. Actually the cause is in the fact that a hashbang doubles as a comment.

Comment: @0xC0000022L : Ohh i never tried in Ubuntu ...got it...thanks a lot for the details